# R - Filtering list of nested lists and finding back a higher level key

Tags: r

I am working on parsing a JSON containing API info for several accounts. This data is used in an api wrapper.

```
[
    {
        "geo":"au",
        "api": [
            {"type":"base_url", "value":"https://api.com"},
            {"type":"key", "value":"f18"},
            {"type":"secret", "value":"569"}
        ],
        "accounts": [
            {"name":"client_AQE","id":"8765","inventory":"all","currency":"AUD"}
       ]
    },{
        "geo":"eu",
        "api": [
            {"type":"base_url", "value":"https://api.com"},
            {"type":"key", "value":"p8c6043"},
            {"type":"secret", "value":"983df5"}
        ],
        "accounts": [
            {"name":"client_UYT","id":"098765","inventory":"all","currency":"GBP"},
            {"name":"client_WER","id":"09098","inventory":"all","currency":"GBP"},
            {"name":"client_OIP","id":"234543","inventory":"all","currency":"EUR"}
        ]
    }
]
```

When the user give me a "account name" but doesn't specify the "geo", I would like to:

1. Check if the client only appears once (this can be done with the function below, using `rlist`)

> ```
> only_one_client <- function(account_name) {
>   return(fromJSON(file=API_INFO_PATH) %>% 
>            list.map(accounts) %>% 
>            unlist(recursive=F) %>% 
>            list.mapv(name) %>% table() %>% extract(account_name) == 1))
> }
> ```

2. If the client only appears once, find the "geo" it appears in

> **This is what I cannot find a way to do**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could transform your JSON into a dataframe holding the each accounts names and the corresponding geo, if `data` is your the result of `fromJSON(file=API_INFO_PATH)` you could do:

```
res <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,lapply(data,function(x) cbind(x[["geo"]],do.call(rbind,x[["accounts"]])))))
colnames(res) <- c("geo",colnames(res[,-1]))

res <- merge(res,as.data.frame(table(res$name)),by.x="name",by.y="Var1")

#        name geo     id inventory currency Freq
#1 client_AQE  au   8765       all      AUD    1
#2 client_OIP  eu 234543       all      EUR    1
#3 client_UYT  eu 098765       all      GBP    1
#4 client_WER  eu  09098       all      GBP    1
```

This basically loops through the list, `rbind` all the accounts and adds the `geo` to each row.

You can then use `table` as in your function to check how many times the `name` appears and which `geo` it comes from.